# How can i pointer char variable add to list char variable in C Programming

Tags: c

i stucked, need to add pointer char value to list char value. pointer char value includes username (windows machine) and list char value includes startup path. I tried to strcat but it breaks the first ";" part.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    char *username = getenv("USERNAME");
    //printf("%s\n", username);  

    char shortcutpath[100] = "C:\\Users\\";"\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup";  //2 ; is weird, i just tried

    strcat(shortcutpath, username);
    printf("%s\n",shortcutpath);
    return 0;
}
```

Output = C:\Users%username%    ,needs to continue

Need to assign a variable "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" this path

Is there any easy way to do that? Or something other usefull things?

Comment: What does this line "C:\\Users\\";"\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup"; mean where there is a string with embedded quotes?!

Comment: Actually path is "C:\\Users\\%username%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup" . ";" is tried to add username variable with strcat(). I tried to add username variable the path

Comment: Please tell us what output you expect

Comment: Well the semi-colon is nonsense since it ends the expression. And then the whole trailing string literal will just be discarded as a null statement. A decent compiler will give a warning here.

Comment: Firstly i want to get device name and go to startup path that user's. I need to go to "C:\\Users\\%username%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup" this path but i couldnt add %username% variable

Comment: OK, so you need to concatenate _three_ strings: `"C:\\Users\\\"`, `%USERNAME%`, and `"\\AppData\\..."`. You can't stick a semicolon in the middle of a string and expect it to magically move the characters around later for you.

Comment: Yes, i just tried, what is the solution? How can i fix this...

Comment: Just call strcat again, it's not rocket science... I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char* username = getenv("USERNAME");
  char shortcutpath[100] = "C:\\Users\\"; 
  strcat(shortcutpath, username);
  strcat(shortcutpath, "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup");

  printf("%s\n", shortcutpath);
  return 0;
}
```

But the more correct way would probably be to get directly the APPDATA environnement variable:

```
int main(void)
  {
    char shortcutpath[100];
    char* appdata = getenv("APPDATA");  // C:\Users\<yourusername>\AppData\Roaming
    strcpy(shortcutpath, appdata);
    strcat(shortcutpath, "\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup");
    ...
```

Comment: Yes it worked, i actually search the short and easy way, (just 1 line). Also tried to python sytnax like variable = "string" + "string2" + "string3". In C  i think we need to add one by one, got it.

Comment: There is no real string type in C, therefore `"string" + "string2" ` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
char shortcutpath[255] = "C:\\Users\\";
strcat(shortcutpath, username);
strcat(shortcutpath, "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup");
```